# How to add text to HTML using javascript when there is no id name or particular class is present inside a tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add some text to my HTML page in an anchor tag using javascript but there is no id,name,or class present inside that anchor tag. Is there any way to do this.
Sample code is given below.

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <span ng-if="smData.standard==smData.stdnr" class="ng-scope"> 
          <a ng-click="m1(a,b)" class="ng-binding" href="/">
              Hello.
          </a> 
        </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Now I want to add something to Hello(say world.)

Comment: How do you know that you want to add some text to that particular anchor element? I.e. what makes it special? Are there other anchor elements in the document?

Comment: You seem to be using Angular, so you should do this the Angular way (which I assume involves things like setting state on a component and then having a template placeholder in the view)

Comment: You are apparently using Angular. But how do you integrate this template? Is this all a component?

Answer (score 2):

Use an attribute selector:

```js
document.querySelector("a[ng-click='m1(a, b)']").innerText += " world.";
```

```html
<a ng-click="m1(a, b)" class="ng-binding" href="/">Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using selectors to track the HTML elements.

Run code snippet.

```js
function reset() {
  document.querySelector("div Table tr span a").innerText += " World!"
  // $("div Table tr span a").text("Hello World");
}
```

```html
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script-->
<button onclick="reset()">Change Text</button>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <span ng-if="smData.standard==smData.stdnr" class="ng-scope"> 
      <a ng-click="m1(a,b)" class="ng-binding" href="/">
          Hello.
      </a> 
    </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks...but I'm looking for an answer without jQuery involved.

Comment: @batman007 same thing, just  swap with `querySelector`. See updated without JQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('a').innerHTML = "(say World)";
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21999829)